# Bootstrap CSS dynamic table accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a possible implementation or idea on how this can and should be done. Essentially, I have a table that I want to make into an accordion and I have been following the one here:

http://www.bootply.com/fdTMNTiLis

The issue is that this implementation sets out for example "#demo1", "#demo2" which is ok for when you know the data and everything but my implementation is for products that are coming from a database and therefore won't exactly know "#demo1" is only the product id.

My question is, is there a more elegant way in order to display this information without the need of creating a hidden row for each one that contains an ID?

Comment: Selecting by `id` is by far the most efficient method of selection in `javaScript`. Besides, I'm pretty sure your products have id's. What's stopping you from adding those to each of their rows?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a database for all data (Job Name-Description-Provider Name-Region  Status) and Thymeleaf for visualization of all data in HTML page.

E.g.

```
<tr th:each="datas : ${data}"
                    th:attr="data-dataId=${data.id}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1" class="accordion-toggle">
              <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button></td>
        <td th:text="|${data.name}|">OBS Name</td>
        <td th:text="|${data.description|">OBS Description</td>
        <td th:text="|${data.cloud}|">hpcloud</td>
        <td th:text="|${data.nova}|">nova</td>
      <td> created</td>

    </tr>
```

Read the guide of [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#introducing-thymeleaf) for more example to use.

You need a Controller.java in our project to job with a database connection